# How do I convert a Java SQL String to SQL in Datagrip?

Tags: java, sql, datagrip

I have a statement in my Java code like so

```
String sql = "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, " +
             " COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7 "  +
             " FROM TABLE T";
```

Is there an easy way to convert/format this as a SQL query (like below) in Datagrip. Similar to what SQLWorkbench does with a "Clean Java Code" by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>?

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3,
       COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7 
       FROM TABLE T
```

Comment: do you mean reformat the query? or convert the sql query in java to sql query?

Comment: @Rias Just convert it from a Java String (copied from codebase), to executable SQL statement which I can then run in a Datagrip console without having to manually strip the quotes and +'s.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the caret on the string literal
2. Press `Alt+Enter`
3. Choose `Copy string concatenation text to clipboard`
   [image: List item]

Comment: What a great TIL - Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to inject proper SQL dialect

select dialect

[image: select dialect]

select specific dialect

[image: select specific dialect]

successful injection

[image: successful injection]

and then edit SQL fragment

[image: edit fragment]

or call `Execute` (Ctrl+Enter) from context menu.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not do what I want. I do not have a java file in DataGrip - just the string so I cannot inject a language and follow this workflow.